# Jenkins step with user interaction and fall through

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

In a declarative Jenkinsfile I have a step for a user interaction to proceed or abort the remainder of the job. After a certain timeout the job terminates.

```
    stage("User Confirmation") {
        steps {
            timeout(time: 5, unit: 'MINUTES') {
                input "Are you sure you want to deploy to ${params.omgeving} ? "
            }
        }
    }
```

However, I'd like to reverse the timeout so that the job **continues** if a user doesn't answer the question. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `try/catch` block to your input https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/230922428-Pipeline-How-to-add-an-input-step-that-continues-if-aborted-using-value

or `catchError/warnError` methods from jenkins https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#catcherror-catch-error-and-set-build-result-to-failure
in your case will be like so

```
stage("User Confirmation") {
  steps {
    script {
      try {
        timeout(time: 5, unit: 'MINUTES') {
          input "Are you sure you want to deploy to ${params.omgeving} ? "
        }
      } catch (err) {
        print("continue")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'd like it to fall through to the next stage.